# Posting to Zapier Hook with Axios in Vue causes CORS error

Tags: forms, vue.js, axios, cors, submit

My form submission is giving me a CORS error when I try to post it to a Zapier Webook endpoint.

This is the form I created:

```
<form @submit.prevent="submitForm()" class="flex flex-col gap-4 mb-8">
    <input class="forminput" type="text" name="name" id="name" v-model="name" placeholder="name" required>
    <input class="forminput" type="email" name="email" id="email" v-model="email" placeholder="you@who.com" required>
    <input class="forminput" type="text" name="submissionTitle" id="submissionTitle" v-model="submissionTitle" placeholder="submission title" required>
    <input class="forminput" type="text" name="submissionLink" id="submissionLink" v-model="submissionLink" placeholder="submission link" required>
    <textarea class="forminput text-left" name="message" id="message" v-model="message" rows="3" placeholder="your message..."></textarea>
    <input class="forminput" type="text" name="instagram" id="instagram" v-model="instagram" placeholder="@instagram">
    <input class="forminput" type="text" name="twitter" id="twitter" v-model="twitter" placeholder="@twitter">
    <input class="bg-purple-700 hover:bg-purple-600 p-1 w-1/4 m-auto font-black text-white rounded-sm shadow-md hover:shadow-lg" type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

This is the logic handling the form submission. I've tried a few different options and snippets here but they all either present a 404 response or a CORS error.

```
<script>
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
    name: 'SubmitPage',
    title: 'Submit Music',
    data () {
        return {
            name: '',
            email: '',
            submissionTitle: '',
            submissionLink: '',
            message: '',
            instagram: '',
            twitter: '',
        }
    },
    methods: {
        submitForm: function () {
            axios.post('hooks.zapier.com/hooks/catch/MYHOOK', {
                name: this.name,
                email: this.email,
                submissionTitle: this.submissionTitle,
                submissionLink: this.submissionLink,
                message: this.message,
                instagram: this.instagram,
                twitter: this.twitter,
    
            })
            .then(function (response) {
                console.log(response);
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });

            alert('Thanks for your submission.');
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

and finally the errors:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://hooks.zapier.com/hooks/catch/MYHOOK/. (Reason: header ‘content-type’ is not allowed according to header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Headers’ from CORS preflight response).

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://hooks.zapier.com/hooks/catch/MYHOOK/. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a third party form service (FlexyForm) instead to handle my form submissions.

This way I avoided having to work around anything and my forms are cleaner.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `transformRequest` property of `axios` to remove the `Content-Type` header. The snippet below removes all the headers from an axios post request and will allow you to send a `post` request to Zapier.

```
axios.create({ transformRequest: [(data, _headers) => JSON.stringify(data)] })
     .post()
```